# ERROR: fixed output name but more than one file to download (ytdl)

Tags: node.js, ytdl

code:

```
  }

exports.downloadVideoYTDL = function(postId, permalink, tempFolder) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ffmpegInstalled()
            .then(function(installed) {
                if (installed) {
                    ytdlInstalled()
                        .then(function(installed2) {
                            if (!installed2) {
                                reject("http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html ");
                                return;
                            }
                            let url = "https://www.reddit.com" + permalink;
                            console.log("YT-DL URL: ", url);
                
                            let downloadLoc = path.join(tempFolder, postId + "-temp.mp4");
                            let command = "youtube-dl -o " + downloadLoc + " " + url
                            console.log(command);
                            exec(command, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                                if (err) {
                                    reject(err);
                                    return;
                                }
```

ERROR:

Error: Command failed: youtube-dl -o D:\Softwares\programming\Insta Bot\redi to insta poster\insta redi poster\temp\qssxlp-temp.mp4 https://www.reddit.com/r/IndianDankMemes/comments/qssxlp/winter_meme_oc/ERROR: fixed output name but more than one file to download
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:383:12)    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)(node:6756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)(node:6756) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Your question is mostly code, what did you do to try fix the issue by yourself ? Please provide more information

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).